# Php word removal from list

Tags: php, html

Edited: i got it to remove names just not from a txt file
Is it possible to read a text file and remove any of the names that are stated in the file from a web page?

namelist.txt looks like this
"jim"
"frank"
"sam"

array output looks like this
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => "jhonny" [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => "jim", "timmy" )

```
 <?php
    //text file location
      $list_name = "list.txt";
      $banlist = file_get_contents($list_name);

//the code i am using to remove the names it works if i put the text in instead of $banlist but i want to enter the names from the list in the txt file
      $htmlclean = preg_replace('/$banlist/', '',$html);

// then after its all the text is done i display withn this is the array
print_r($matches[1][2]);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is in the input file?  We need a [mcve].  We don't need to see all of your script; only the part that you need help with.

Comment: just a .txt file with a list of names in it the page currently displays a list of names eg "jim" "frank" "bob". the page displays with the "" i just want to be able to enter "frank" in the text file and it gets removed from the array

Comment: Currently, we cannot help you because your question is incomplete.  Please edit.

Comment: I believe it is updated to what is needed? please let me know if i am still incorrect

Comment: There is far too much yatta-yatta here.  Show us a minimal and realistic sample input (contents of the input file so that we can understand the text format/structure). Show us exactly how you are processing the data.  Show us the EXACT desired output from your sample input.  Explain how your attempt is failing.  If there are any errors generated, paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: ok i cut it right down and reworded  the question so it is shorter and included examples from the array output and text file